# Permission denied with error info?

Tags: django, permission-denied

in Django is there an official way to return PermissionDenied exception with some text of error info as response body to browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the docs have official viewpoints.

> In the same vein as the 404 and 500 views, Django has a view to handle
>   403 Forbidden errors. If a view results in a 403 exception then Django
>   will, by default, call the view
>   django.views.defaults.permission_denied.
>
> This view loads and renders the template 403.html in your root
>   template directory, or if this file does not exist, instead serves the
>   text "403 Forbidden", as per RFC 2616 (the HTTP 1.1 Specification).

Comment: link to (modern) [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/views/#the-403-http-forbidden-view)  also from same documentation: "The template context contains exception, which is the string representation of the exception that triggered the view."